# Alternating rows based on a value of a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, alternating

I have a problem with selecting alternating rows in mysql - 
Image:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

And want to be able to select rows from images table in such a way as to have alternating values of project_id IS NOT NULL. Basically:

- image with project_id
- image without project_id
- image with project_id
- image without project_id
- image with project_id
- image without project_id

How can this be accomplished in one SQL query? I've tried:

```
SELECT `images`.*, 
IF(images.project_id, images.project_id % 2, images.id % 2) AS `mixer`
FROM `images` AS `images`
ORDER BY `mixer` DESC
```

But it's not what I need. Also the final query will probably have a "GROUP BY images.id" in it so if the solution does not mess up the query that would be quite welcome.

Comment: `group by images.id` (*unique field*) doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to get doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting challenge. Try this:

```
SELECT images.*, 
FROM images, (SELECT @x:=-1, @y:=0) c
ORDER BY CASE WHEN project_id is not null THEN @x:=@x+2 ELSE @y:=@y+2 END;
```

This works by incrementing one of two values `@x` and `@y` based on the condition and having the value you want ordered first start with a lower initial value. The result of the evaluation is in the range `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` as can be seen from running:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN project_id is not null THEN @x:=@x+2 ELSE @y:=@y+2 END z, images.*, 
FROM images, (SELECT @x:=-1, @y:=0) c
ORDER BY z;
```

Comment: Interesting solution too! I wonder if limiting the calculations to integers only could give it a tiny little boost.

Comment: @AndriyM: Thanks. Quite probable. Updated answer to use integers instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot it actually does work, however the performance is really terrible - For a table of about 70 000 I get 5 seconds query. Is there a way to actually make this work faster? Maybe cache some of the information inside the table itself?

Comment: You could add an indexed column with the sort value to your table, but then you'd also have to update it for every update and insert.